# What is the best way to work with android fragment backstack?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working with multiple fragments with only one Activity and I want to know how to manage fragment backstack on back press (the best way)

Any link or little explanation with some code can be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example fragment backstack on back press :

`FragmentsActivity` is the activity which will be the container for all your fragments, so override FragmentsActivity's `onBackPressed()`  like this -

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val fm = supportFragmentManager
        if (fm.backStackEntryCount > 0) { //if backstack contain any fragment than pop it
            fm.popBackStack()
        } else {                          // call super function normally 
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Now whenever launch a fragment like this -

```
//If you don't want it in backstack
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentA())
.commit() 

//If you want it in backstack
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.fragment_container, FragmentA())
.addToBackStack(null)           //null or any String TAG you want
.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to make sure you call [.addToBackStack(null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) in [Fragment Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager) and [Fragment Transaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use Android Jetpack Navigation. A new and improved way to handle fragment transactions. This is way better than the old `FragmentTransaction` class method. It is highly recommended by Google itself. And I'm also learning it nowadays.
There's a tutorial below.

[Android Jetpack - Navigation](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6014-the-navigation-architecture-component-tutorial-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

**Backpress on Fragments**

Need your fragment to be notified when user presses back button?

The Dumb Way :

**MyFragment.kt**

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this,
    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // user pressed back button
        }
    })
```

The Rockstar Developer Way :

**Add this dependency:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher.html

> implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0-rc01'

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
    // user pressed back button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common answer for this query is to pop the backstack or navigate up to previous activity. What if you dont want to pop the backstack on a certain fragment?

Override your onbackpressed to handle these conditions:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

    when(supportFragmentManager.fragments[0].javaClass.simpleName){
        "FragmentOne" -> doActionOne()
        "FragmentTwo" -> doActionTwo()
        ...
        else -> supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

this gets your name of your current fragment and then you decide what you would want to do. For example maybe for one of the fragments you want a dialog to ask "are you sure you want to leave?" ect.